# On Click CSS Property like BuySellAds

Tags: css

I have tried to make this CSS property on-click work the same as what can be found here: buysellads.com, If you click on the logo, the moment you click on it, it pads down a little...

How can we create that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this, it might do the trick:

```
.logo a:active { position: relative; top: 1px; }
```

If it doesn't work you probably have some other CSS that's preventing this effect from working. Can you provide a URL to your site so we can check it out?

Cheers

Comment: Currently I am working offline, its just an HTML+CSS... Let me show you the logo area code

Comment: .textlogo a {
font-family: 'Terminal Dosis', sans-serif;
 color: #000;
 font-weight:bold;
 margin-top:10px;
 float:left;
 font-size:30px;
 text-decoration: none;
}


.textlogo a:hover{
color:#666;cursor: pointer;
padding-top:2px;
}

Comment: Thanks, something like the following should work: `.textlogo a { font-family: 'Terminal Dosis', sans-serif; color: #000; font-weight: bold; margin-top: 10px; float: left; font-size: 30px; text-decoration: none; } .textlogo a:hover { color: #666; } .textlogo a:active { position: relative; top: 1px; }` (see the a:active portion) and here's a quick demo: http://jonphillips.ca/files/junaid.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the background position on active:

```
.logo a:active em {
background-position: 8px 7px;
}
```

line 201 - 203 in their styles.css